# Why is preconnect resource hint not working?

Tags: html, web-performance, preconnect

I've created a test page at [crenshaw.dev/demo/hints.html](http://crenshaw.dev/demo/hints.html) with browser hints requesting a dns-prefetch and preconnect to mac9416.com.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Test resource hints</title>
        <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//mac9416.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://mac9416.com" crossorigin>
    </head>
    <body>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <!-- a bunch more to delay page loading -->
        Duis dignissim gravida commodo.

        <script src="https://mac9416.com/blah.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But [according to WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/190404_GN_22e5f44350231bcee5b6d59c03c2ba22/1/details/#waterfall_view_step1), the connection to mac9416.com isn't happening until after index.html is fully loaded.

[image: WebPageTest waterfall chart showing mac9416.com is connected to only after all markup has been downloaded and parsed, instead of immediately after the head element is parsed]

Why isn't Chrome connecting to mac9416.com immediately after `<head>` is parsed?

**UPDATE:**

Based on the accepted answer and comment, I [wrote up](https://crenshaw.dev/preconnect-resource-hint-crossorigin-attribute) an explanation of the fix.

> The `crossorigin` attribute, when used with `rel="preconnect"`, doesn't describe *where the target origin is* but rather *what kind of assets will be downloaded from that origin*. If the assets use CORS, `crossorigin` is needed. If CORS won't be used, `crossorigin` should be omitted. If both types of assets will be present, two resource hints are necessary.

Comment: Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/89466/10249

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just remove the badly named *crossorigin* parameter and it will work.

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://mac9416.com">
```

This parameters doesn't tell the browser that the domain is external (it already knows that). It tells the browser to pre-open a special "CORS" connection, which is needed for fonts or XHR requests, but not for scripts, stylesheets or images.

Comment: Test checks out. After some reading, I see that omitting `crossorigin` basically means "don't use CORS". Out of curiosity, how might one get the preconnect to work _while_ using CORS?

Comment: Scripts don’t use CORS. So did a preconnect for a CORS connection and then requested a non-CORS asset type, which uses a separate connection. If it was a font request or a XHR request then it should have used that CORS connection that you preconnected too. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#What_requests_use_CORS