# How to further mitigate bad web vitals LCP results?

Tags: html, pagespeed, lighthouse, core-web-vitals, web-vitals

I am having a tough time reducing my mobile FCP and LCP stats, being 3.6s and 5.5s respectively.

I've read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77042837/why-is-my-load-delay-really-high-for-my-lcp), done all of the suggested points already and I still face a huge Load Delay for my LCP.

- My LCP is a `<picture>` inside a Bootstrap Carousel used as background
- The `<picture>` has various sources, among others a webp and a resized webp version:

```
<picture >
    <source srcset="http://localhost:8888/image.webp" type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 576px)">
    <source srcset="http://localhost:8888/image_xs.webp" type="image/webp" media="(max-width: 575px)">
    ^^^ this is the one that gets used for the LCP
    <source srcset="http://localhost:8888/image.jpg" type="image/jpeg" media="(min-width: 576px)">
    <source srcset="http://localhost:8888/image_xs.jpg" type="image/jpeg" media="(max-width: 575px)">
    <img src="http://localhost:8888/image.jpg" alt="alt" >
</picture>
```

- I added a `<link rel="preload" fetchpriority="high" as="image" href="http://localhost:8888/image_xs.webp" type="image/webp" media="all">` and in the dev tools network tab I see that it's actually the first source being loaded. It's 14 kB and takes 2 ms to load.

So, running Lighthouse locally in dev tools I still get a Load Delay of 3800 - 4000 ms in the LCP which is weird to me since the whole page, according to the network tab (after running LH), just takes ~400ms.

I guess that Load Delay does not describe when the image source was loaded, does it? Does it describe the delay the renderer takes to actually correctly display that element? If the latter, I really dont know what else to improve. I have 2 CSS files, one just being bootstrap, one custom, both minified and gzipped and combined below 50 kB. Even packing them into one file doesnt change a thing.

I only get 2 diagnostic recommendations by Lighthouse. The first one being to "Eliminate render-blocking resources" with a potential saving of 2,700 ms. As said, I only have 2 stylesheets though, bootstrap.min.css and my minified main.min.css. I cannot split their positioning or put them at the end of the page because that would result in more red flags popping up, like Layout Shifts and effectively halfing my performance score.

Google recommends putting inline styles in the top elements and after that to load the stylesheets which sounds like madness to me and is actually impossible for many big sites and I am really confused that anything other than that will be punished.

The second entry is just the big LCP element in general:

| Phase | % of LCP | Timing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TTFB | 8% | 450 ms |
| Load Delay | 68% | 3,720 ms |
| Load Time | 1% | 40 ms |
| Render Delay | 23% | 1,280 ms |

Also, Lighthouse in dev tools asks me to minify the js of chrome extensions which sounds weird...

So, any idea what I am missing? I am currently playing around with mod_pagespeed on Apache, maybe that will help.

Edit

In the Performance tab I actually see better results for my LCP and FCP after implementing a lot of the measures. I still dont understand the LH reports.

Comment: Something doesn't add up- if you're preloading the LCP image and it's the first resource loaded, the load delay should be much lower than 3.7s. Are you sure it's the LCP image?

Comment: @RickViscomi 100%. I added a coloured dot for each variant of the image and the preview in the report shows a yellow circle, which is only existent in the _xs.webp image.

Comment: Agreed with Rick that something's going wrong here. Load delay is the time from TTFB for the HTML document to when the LCP image starts downloading. If the image is preloaded, it seems not possible that load delay would be that slow (and it would seemingly place the image not loading until after FCP?). Something very odd is happening. It's also possible it's a [Lighthouse bug](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues). Unfortunately it's difficult to tell more without being able to load the site to reproduce. Could you share a copy of the Lighthouse report?

Comment: "Google recommends putting inline styles in the top elements and after that to load the stylesheets" - Also, FWIW, this is recommending an inline `<style>` block containing critical CSS for quick FCP, not inline styles on individual elements, which would indeed be madness. See e.g. [Defer non-critical CSS](https://web.dev/articles/defer-non-critical-css).

There are definitely tradeoffs in maintainability, utility, and performance doing that, so you should only do so if there's a real improvement.

Regardless, it's not the cause of a long LCP load delay if the preload is working correctly

Comment: @BrendanKenny Thanks for that input, that gives me hope. I do believe it might be some kind of bug. I will soon deploy all updates on an online preview and try to run the tests on there. Also, thanks for clarifying the inline thing :)

Comment: It looks like your preload is targeting the image that the Lighthouse test happens to use. In real life, it may be the other image. So, I would have two preloads using the same media restrictions as the picture tag. Is this site only in dev for now?

Comment: @TonyMcCreath I dont quite understand what you mean. I added the preload because LH mobile will load/ show that image. The site is also online under a preview URL but Im still figuring out mod_pagespeed stuff there first. But it looks like the report results are quite similar to my local machine

Comment: Your preload mechanism must cater to all users, not just the one Lighthouse simulates. Your picture does that with the source media combination. I believe the preload can also do that with the media attributes.